# How to Iterator according the ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, io

```
 public class Buffer {

    byte[] buffer;

    public Buffer(int size) {
        buffer = new byte[size];
    }
    public byte[] toByteArray() {
        return buffer;
    }

    public Iterator<Object> iterator() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
        return new Iterator<Object>() {
            public boolean hasNext(){} //How to knnow next Object by ObjectInputStream 
            public Object next(){} ;// How to move to next Object
    }}
```

what does `in.readObject()` at this time?
I doubt with how to get the buffer object and how move to next Object?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.
The iterator returned has 'next' and 'hasNext' methods

```
public Iterator<Object> iterator() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
    
    
    Iterator<Object> itr=null;
    ArrayList<Object> L = new ArrayList<Object>();
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Object read = (Object) in.readObject();
         
             L.add(read);
        }
    }
    
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        itr = L.iterator();
    }
    
    return itr;
}
```